# Custom Post 'Post Per Page’ Crashing Page?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

Has anyone encountered this before?

A normal page template with a custom post type query on it. However, when it gets to a set amount of posts the page crashes, white space below where the query sits no footer no nothing.

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'team-section','posts_per_page' => '-1') ); ?>
```

However, if i change the posts per page to 21 the page loads fine.

If i change it to 22 only a few posts are loaded, rest of page is white.

23, back to the whole page below the header being white again.

There are actually 24 posts in the team-section and the site reading settings are set to 1, but it still does it if i set that to 24 as well.

Is it something to do with the php memory or something along those lines?

edit. updated with WP_Query

```
    <?php
                    $teamPosts = new WP_Query();
                        $teamPosts->query('post_type=team-section&showposts=-1');
                        while ($teamPosts->have_posts()) : $teamPosts->the_post(); ?>

                            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </li>


                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: TIP: go back and rewrite your query with `WP_Query`. **NEVER** use `query_posts`, it does break many things, and one is pagination. If you have rewritten your query, and you still experience the same issue, please file an [edit] with an update

Comment: Also, you should make sure your have `WP_DEBUG` set to `true` in your `wp-config.php` file, so that you can see a explanation of the failure instead of white space.

Comment: Thank you both, in implemented WP_QUERY and also increased the memory limit in the wp-config file to 100m and now it shows all the posts.